# Disable Reactive Form's Input Fields

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

[image]

The image shows how my form fields appears. I want to know what is the best way to disabled rest form input fields when user type in 'Discount Percentage' and its relevant 'Remark'.

Ex 1:- If user type in Discount Percentage field then Discount Amount, Additional Loading Percentage and Additional Loading amount and their relevant Remark fields will be Disabled.

Ex 2:- If user type in Additional Loading Amount field then Discount Amount, Additional Loading Percentage and Discount Percentage and their relevant Remark fields will be Disabled.

If user clear the input field then disabled input fields should be enabled again.

```
    formGroup = new FormGroup({
        discountPercentage: new FormControl(),
        discountPercentageRemark: new FormControl(''),
        discountAmount: new FormControl(),
        discountAmountRemark: new FormControl(''),
        loadingPercentage: new FormControl(),
        loadingPercentageRemark: new FormControl(''),
        loadingAmount: new FormControl(),
        loadingAmountRemark: new FormControl('')
  })
```

Comment: Please pass your HTML code

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe for the changes in discountPercentage field in ngOnInit and set the disable property on template according to that;

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.formGroup.get('discountPercentage').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
  if(value) {
     this.isDiscountPercantageHasValue = true;
    } else {
     this.isDiscountPercantageHasValue = false;
    }
  })
}
```

and in your template file you can set it like below;

```
<input type="text" formControlName="discountAmount" [disabled]="isDiscountPercantageHasValue" .../>
```

Comment: Then how to disabled the form relevant form fields? Otherwise you set Validators to required. I don't need that option.

Comment: opps! my bad. Updated my answer.